# Discrete colorbar in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I want to visualize my simple time-series data in Python as a discrete colorbar, but with each line color intensity being the score. Scores are percentages. The higher the score, the more intense the color.

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,...
0,0,0,40,0,99,...
```

And here is a sample illustration. How can I achieve this in Python and save the image? The data can be many records, showing scores of items over time. So it should just be a well-visible line, not really 1-unit! Overall the relative occurance of events according to time is important.

[image]

Comment: Unless you have a screen which is "thousands of" pixels wide, some bars will necessarily not be shown, right? Is that expected?

Comment: Haha good question. It's more about visualizing the non-0 parts. And also assume my records are smaller.

Comment: Should such a line be 1 unit wide? In that case you can use a `plt.bar` plot. Or should it be just a line? In that case you can use a `plt.hlines` plot.

Comment: Not really 1-unit! Should just be a well-visible line. Overall the relative occurance of events according to time is important. If you can share a working snippet, that would be great.

Comment: well-visible lines can be achieved by increasing the lines' thicknesses.

Comment: OK. Please share a sample also to give you credits.